# Tensors on parallelizable manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Lets say we have a manifold $\mathcal{M}$ and the frame bundle $F\mathcal{M}$ has as structure group some subgroup $G$ of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$. In such a case one can find the "invariant tensor(s)" i.e. tensors that transform according to the trivial representation of $G$.

1) Could somebody give me some examples of this? Like a list with three entries: the manifold $\mathcal{M}$, the group $G$ and the invariant tensor(s).

2) In particular if $G$ is trivial (this is the same than saying $\mathcal{M}$ is parallelizable) all tensors are invariant right? How is it possible to have tensors that do not change components at all?

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a partial misunderstanding in your question. You say that $F\mathcal M$ "has as structure group some subgroup $G$ of $GL(n,\mathbb R)$". The frame bundle itself always has structure group  $GL(n,\mathbb R)$, but it may be possible to choose a reduction to a certain subgroup $G\subset GL(n,\mathbb R)$. But this is a choice, which introduces an additional structure on $\mathcal M$, and the invariant tensors depend on this additional structure.

For some groups $G$, such a reduction can be chosen on any manifold. For example putting $G=O(n)$ such a reduction is equivalent to the choice of a Riemannian metric $g$ on $\mathcal M$. The simplest examples of invariant tensors are then the metric $g$ itself, its inverse or the volume density determined by $g$.

For other groups $G$, reductions exist only under additional assumptions on $\mathcal M$. This is the case for the trivial group $\{I\}\subset GL(n,\mathbb R)$, for which a reduction exists only for parallelizable manifolds. But again the reduction itself is a choice, namely the choice of a global trivialization of the tangent bundle. (And there are many such choices, fixing one they are described by all smooth functions $\mathcal M\to GL(n,\mathbb R)$. Fixing such a global trivialization, you get global frames for all tensor bundles, and the invariant tensors then are exactly those tensors which have constant coordinates in that global frame.

Comment: Hi Andreas thank you for the answer. Could you please elaborate a bit on the idea:       " For example putting G=O(n) such a reduction is equivalent to the choice of a Riemannian metric g on M".

Comment: Things are quite easy if you use the picture that the fiber of $\mathcal FM$ over $x\in M$ is the set of all linear isomorphisms from $\mathbb R^n$ to $T_xM$. Clearly, $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ acts freely and transitively on this set. A reduction to $O(n)$ gives you a subset on which the subgroup $O(n)$ acts transitively. If you endow $\mathbb R^n$ with the standard inner product then you can carry this over to $T_xM$ with any of the chosen Isomorphisms. Since they are rleated by the action of $O(n)$, they all lead to the same result, so you get an inner product on each tangent space.